# Sage pay error 5003 and http error 500 after moving web servers

Tags: server, opayo

Guy please can you help

I have recently moved web servers from OLD IP to a NEW IP and already done a DNS change.

The new server works fine, and the website https://www.rgbdirect.co.uk is working however when I add an item and check out I have a problem.

The website will pass the sale to sage https://live.sagepay.com/gateway/service/cardselection?

Which displays all the correct details such as select card details however if we press cancel we get an error 5003 and an error 500. The redirect page does not work either, and Sagepay says they are not receiving any data from our notificationpage.asp which should be talking back to sagepage.

The strange thing is if I change my host file on my pc and change the IP address for www.rgbdirect.co.uk, so I am looking at our old server when I get to the https://live.sagepay.com/gateway/service/cardselection? And then press the cancel button sage can now receive information from the notificationpage.asp which is coming from our NEW server which we have confirmed it is not coming from the OLD server.

I can't understand how sagepay can read our notification page through our old server however from our NEW server they cannot read the page at all.

We have installed a brand new SSL certificate just in case it was an SSL certificate issue. However, this has not resolved the issue.

The other thing I noticed is that from our new server sage pay instantly gives an error when we click on the cancel button on the https://live.sagepay.com/gateway/service/cardselection? Page however on the old server it is looking for a notificationpage.asp and times out after some time not instantly.

Anybody, please help

Comment: Have you set your new IP in the Sage Pay admin panel? `Sage Pay Server` and `Sage Pay Direct` both use your server's IP address for authentication.

Comment: I have added valid ip addresses so they are not blocked. However in the may sage pay I don't see anything regards server ip address.

Comment: Just a thought. It's not a TLS 1.2 issue is it? I seem to remember classic ASP doesn't work with TLS1.2 (though I think there are registry hacks you can do to enable it)